# HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem never executes on azure deployed asp.net mvc 4.5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have an asp.net 4.5 app deployed to azure.
The service plan is Standard (S2) 2 cores

I have a long running task, that needs to be executed in fire-and-forget manner after a get request to an action method.

But even with the following test code:

```
    public ActionResult TestItem()
    {
        // test method source is below
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => this.Context.TestMethod(););
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }


    public void TestMethod()
        {
             using (var conn = _connectionFactory.Create())
             {
                 conn.Open();
                 conn.Execute("INSERT INTO web.HotelSearchQueue (HSQ_ID) VALUES(@id)", new { @id = Guid.NewGuid() });
             }
        }
```

nothing happens. Of course this is working fine on the DEV machine and it is also working when called directly, blocking the request thread.

Any idea what may cause that problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue. After calling support they advised me to place additional option in Application Settings of Azure App Service "**WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE**" with value "**0**". This is temporary fix and they said that update will be available in future which will allow avoid of using this setting.

Comment: Here we are about a year later and I am having some goofy, but similar, issue with QueueBackgrounWorkItem, as well. I call this method to spawn a background task to upload a file to a remote server. I have 4 PDF streams to upload. 3 of them will upload and one will not no matter if I try to queue up 4 background tasks to send the files or just one background task to send the one problem PDF. It's always the same PDF that fails. And there's no exception thrown or anything. The background method is just never started. When I call the method on the main thread the file is successfully sent.